# Swiftui NavigationLink not executing

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to but a NavigationLink in a LazyVGrid and I'm having a bit of trouble with the navigation. I would like that when the color is clicked that I could segue to the next page. Here is some code:

Here is how the start page looks [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzngW.png)

Here is how the image card is set up:

```
    ZStack{
        Color(colorData.image)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding(8)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: colorData.image, in: animation)
    }
```

Here is how the LazyVgrid is set up:

```
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                
                VStack{
                    
                    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 15), count: 2),spacing: 15){
                        
                        ForEach(bags){color in
                            
                            ColorView(colorData: color,animation: animation)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation(.easeIn){
                                        print("pressed")
                                        selectedColor = color
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.top,10)
                }
            })
        }
```

Here is how I navigate:

```
        if selectedColor != nil {
        
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {}
            
        }
```

Comment: could you show some more code? Where is selectBag defined? You could also try just wrapping the ColorView in a NavigationLink to DetailView.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as mentioned in [@workingdog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68592227), or slightly modify the code like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isActive: Bool = false
    @State var selectedColor: Color?

   var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsVieww(selectedColor: selectedColor), isActive: $isActive) {
            EmptyView()
    }
    VStack {
            ColorView(colorData: color, animation: animation)
                .onTapGesture {
                selectedColor = color
               isActive = true
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typically with navigation you would do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Int?
    @State var selectedColor: Color?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {  // <--- required somewhere in the hierarchy of views
            // ....
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailsVieww(selectedColor: selectedColor),
                           tag: 1,
                           selection: $selection) {
                ColorView(colorData: color, animation: animation)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                            selectedColor = color
                            selection = 1   // <--- will trigger just the tag=1 NavigationLink
                        }
                    }
            }
            // ....
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsVieww: View {
    @State var selectedColor: Color?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("selected color view \(selectedColor?.description ?? "")")
    }
}
```